# Unable to read inbox sms into list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to read all SMS from inbox and show these sms in the list view.

Problems I am facing are:

1) I am getting List "msgList" as blank, Also the List "labeles" [from method getSms()] as blank. I have 2 sms in inbox.

2)It never prints hhhhhhh+labeles in for loop.

Can anybody suggest me changes in following code so that i can read inbox sms and list them into listView ? exactly where i gone wrong ?

I have written following code : **ViewTask.java**

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewTask extends Activity {

TextView tv_view_task;
ListView lv_view_task;
static String sms = "";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_task);
    tv_view_task=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_view_task);
    lv_view_task=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_view_task);

    List<String> msgList = getSms();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msgList); 
      lv_view_task.setAdapter(adapter); 
}

public List<String> getSms()
{
    List<String> labeles = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);

    // Read the sms data and store it in the list
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        for(int i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

            sms += "From :" + c.getString(2) + " : " + c.getString(11)+"\n"; 
            labeles.add(sms);
            System.out.println("hhhhhh"+labeles);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
    System.out.println("aaaaaaa"+labeles);
    return labeles;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_view_task, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is my activity_view_task.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_tasks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Tasks"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_view_task"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_tasks"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMsg"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_msg" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FormActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_form" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_details" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainPageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_page" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewTaskActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_task" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewTask"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_task" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application> </manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: using permissions ?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>

Comment: Yes i have already written this permission code in my manifest file....

Comment: works great for me, the only thing is that "c.getString(11)" returns null... maybe that breaks your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method..

```
public List<String> getSms() {
    List<String> labeles = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    String sms = null;

    // Read the sms data and store it in the list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
            String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
            sms = "From : " + address + " : " + body;
            labeles.add(sms);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    // System.out.println("aaaaaaa" + labeles);
    return labeles;
}
```

**Note**:Dont forgot to add the permission..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.. **to read the inbox messages**

Comment: Are you getting the **labels** atleast.. ?

Comment: Any messages in **inbox** ??

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in your code try this one

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewTask extends Activity {

TextView tv_view_task;
ListView lv_view_task;
static String sms = "";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_task);
    tv_view_task=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_tasks);
    lv_view_task=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_view_task);

    List<String> msgList = getSms();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msgList); 
      lv_view_task.setAdapter(adapter); 
}

public List<String> getSms()
{
    List<String> labeles = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);

    // Read the sms data and store it in the list
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        for(int i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

            sms += "From :" + c.getString(2) + " : " + c.getString(11)+"\n"; 
            labeles.add(sms);
            Log.i("meenal","hhhhhh"+labeles);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
    Log.i("meenal","aaaaaaa"+labeles);
    return labeles;
}
```

}

and your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_tasks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Tasks"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_view_task"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_tasks"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</ListView>
```

and in manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.imaegcolourchange.ViewTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```